# Euler's method produces mirrored solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, eulers-method

I have the differential equation
$$ 0.22y'' + y' + 10000y = 2000\pi \cos (2000 \pi t) $$

from this I get the Euler's method system of equations:
$$ t_{n+1} = t_n + 0.001 $$
$$ x_{n+1} = x_n + 0.001\left(\frac{2000\pi \cos(2000\pi t) - 10000y_n-x_n}{0.22}\right) $$
$$ y_{n+1} = y_n + 0.001x_n $$

and using Microsoft Excel to fill a spreadsheet with approximations using the Excel equations

t_n $\text{=B3+0.001}$

x_n $\text{=C3+0.001*(2000*PI()*COS(2000*PI()*B3)-10000*D3-C3)/0.22}$

y_n $\text{=D3+0.001*C3}$

where the initial conditions are B3=0, C3=1/0.22 and D3=0, and then obviously dragging down so the cell references update each time.

Plotting this data with Excel shows

[image]

while the true solution is mirrored, where the amplitude starts off high and slowly dampens.

Where am I going wrong in Euler's method.

Comment: There is something wrong about your discrete equations... the time step seems to vary from one equation to the other.

Comment: @PierreCarre oh thanks for pointing that out but that was just a copying error, in the Excel  equations ts consistent

Comment: The step size is too large. To even properly sample the $1000$ oscillations per time unit of the right side, you need about $10\,000$ samples per time unit, that is, a step size of $10^{-4}$

Comment: @LutzLehmann thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

It is a linear equation, you can compute the exact solution quite easily...
$$
y(t)=\sin (213.201 x) (0.0110345 \sin
   (6069.98 x)+0.0103102 \sin (6496.39 x))+\cos
   (213.201 x) (-0.0110345 \cos (6069.98
   x)+0.0103102 \cos (6496.39 x)+4.54618)
$$

In fact, there will be no dampening.

Comment: Thanks, but that wasn't really the question.

Comment: @Matt My point is that no dampening should be observed, because it does not exist.